# Finding the absolute path of a running jar in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, process

I have a java process running a jar in a linux vm. I ran "ps -ef | grep java" command and I get the following--

```
 odosvc   14700 23904  5 03:45 ?        00:00:21 java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:ErrorFile=/logs/osd-service-api/HS_ERR_PID%p.log -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:-ResizePLAB -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/cacerts -jar target/osd-service-api-0.1.31.jar server target/config/oc1.conf
```

I wanted to find the full path of the osd-service-api-0.1.31.jar. I ran the following

pwdx 14700 and I got the following==

```
pwdx 14700
14700: /etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api
```

This is still printing the relative path. In the VM there are many folder paths of the above form which contains jar of the same name and hence I am not able to find the absolute path of the jar which is actually running. Is there some way I can get the absolute path of the running jar?

Comment: `/etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api` is an **absolute** path, not a relative one.

Comment: No it is a relative path, i couldnot find it from the root folder, although there are many "/etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api" folders inside our project folder.

Comment: A start starting with `/` is, by definition, an absolute path, and it is not surprising, that  it is not inside your **project** folder, becaus you likely don't have your project somewhere under `/etc`. If you do a `ls -dl /etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api`, you will find that path.

Comment: You can learn about the difference between this types of pathes [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/absolute-vs-relative-path/).

Comment: Maybe you have read it wrong, it IS inside my project folder. Also running the above command gives --ls -dl /etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api
ls: cannot access /etc/runit/artifacts/osd-service-api: No such file or directory

Comment: I suggest thta you add the output of this `ls` command to your question, instead of keeping it in a comment. Maybe it gives someone with good knowledge about the Java runtime environment a clue about what's going on. For me, it is strange because `pwdx` is supposed to output the _working directory_ of a process, and I can not understand how the working directory can be a non-existent directory.